# IOException parsing XML document from class path resource - file does not exist - Spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, junit4

I'm aware that this question about the spring xml config file not been found in execution has been asked several times before, but none of the other answers seems to work for me.

I'm trying to run some test in a Maven Project with Spring and JUnit and I get this error all the time:

> T E S T S
>   Running es.udc.jcastedo.NosaTenda.test.model.productoService.ProductoServiceTest
>   12-ago-2014 13:37:33 org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager retrieveTestExecutionListeners
>   INFO: Could not instantiate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener]. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes (and their required dependencies) available. Offending class: [javax/servlet/ServletContext]
>   12-ago-2014 13:37:33 org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
>   INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@2f8bbc98: startup date [Tue Aug 12 13:37:33 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
>   12-ago-2014 13:37:33 org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
>   INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [nosaTenda-spring-config.xml]
>   Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.225 sec <<< FAILURE!
>
> Results :
>
> Tests in error: 
>   es.udc.jcastedo.NosaTenda.test.model.productoService.ProductoServiceTest
>   es.udc.jcastedo.NosaTenda.test.model.productoService.ProductoServiceTest: Could not initialize class es.udc.jcastedo.NosaTenda.test.model.util.DbUtil
>
> Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0

This is a link to the complete trace of the surefire report: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2635926/es.udc.jcastedo.NosaTenda.test.model.productoService.ProductoServiceTest.txt

Where you can find this lines:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [nosaTenda-spring-config.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [nosaTenda-spring-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
>
> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [nosaTenda-spring-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
>
> es.udc.jcastedo.NosaTenda.test.model.productoService.ProductoServiceTest  Time elapsed: 0.003 sec  <<< ERROR!
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class es.udc.jcastedo.NosaTenda.test.model.util.DbUtil
>     at es.udc.jcastedo.NosaTenda.test.model.productoService.ProductoServiceTest.cleanDb(ProductoServiceTest.java:52)

DbUtil is an auxiliary class called by all tests, where the context is initialized:

```
public class DbUtil {
    static {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("nosaTenda-spring-config.xml");
        transactionManager = (PlatformTransactionManager) context
            .getBean("transactionManager");
        productoDao = (ProductoDao) context.getBean("productoDao");
        tiendaDao = (TiendaDao) context.getBean("tiendaDao");
    }

    ...

    public static void populateDb() {
    ...
    }
    public static void cleanDb() throws Throwable {
    ...
    }
}
```

Apparently there lays the problem, as it seems the xml config file is not found no matter what and it breaks at the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext method call.

Theoretically, the spring config file is located where it should be, in src/main/resources.

I have tried all combinations, from the qualified name "/NosaTenda/src/main/resources/nosaTenda-spring-config.xml" to "nosaTenda-spring-config.xml", with the same result.

I don't know what's wrong with the class path, or if the problem is elsewhere.

EDIT

Here is the pom of the project, I just remembered that I added some filtering in the build-resources section, maybe I did something wrong there and that's the problem.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2635926/pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution, it was somewhere else.

I was using a Run Configuration with the ***forkMode none*** parameter, as I was running a single test class. ***forkMode*** apparently is deprecated and was causing the problem. I replaced it with ***forkCount 0*** and worked just fine, it found the spring xml config file, and even the test version overwriting some parameters, so perfect. Now I just have to debug a ton of other errors that the configuration has :)

```
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [nosaTenda-spring-config.xml]
12-ago-2014 17:42:09 org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [nosaTenda-spring-config-test.xml]
12-ago-2014 17:42:09 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory registerBeanDefinition
INFO: Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [nosaTenda-spring-config.xml]] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [nosaTenda-spring-config-test.xml]]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generally your classpath would be .../src/main/java/, and ClassPathXmlApplicationContext would read from .../src/main/resources.
Then your test classes would be in .../src/test/java/ and ClassPathXmlApplicationContext would read from .../src/test/resources.

So, check where your test application context is, and put a copy of the xml there.

Comment: Actually, I have a test version of the spring config file, intended to overwrite some attributes in a mechanism to use a different database for testing, but that's not important now.

I have tried with this other xml file located in src/test/resources, from "/NosaTenda/src/test/resources/nosaTenda-spring-config-test.xml" to "nosaTenda-spring-config-test.xml", same result.

So I don't know, maybe the mistake is in a completely different place? How can I know where is looking for the xml file?


PD: Thanks for the fast answer.